# Groovy Properties Assertion Fails

Tags: properties, groovy, assert

Here is the content of my groovy file:

```
def KEY = "a"

Properties myProp = new Properties()
myProp[KEY] = "b"
assert(myProp[KEY] == myProp.getProperty(KEY))

Properties results = new Properties(myProp)
assert(results[KEY] == results.getProperty(KEY))
```

I expected both asserts to pass but only the first assert passes and the second assert fails.

Any explanation to this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when the docs say "creates an empty property list", that's what it does:

```
println(results)
>>> [:]
```

Check out what `getProperty` does:

> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property list. If the key is not found in this property list, the default property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked. The method returns null if the property is not found.

Leading to the conclusion that the `[]` (`getAt`) does *not* search the default property list.

We can pursue this to see how Groovy implements `getAt`:

```
public static <K,V> V getAt(Map<K,V> self, K key) {
    return self.get(key);
}
```

So it's calling the underlying `Hashtable`'s `get` method, which knows nothing about the default property list--defaults are part of `Properties`, not `Hashtable`:

```
println(results.getProperty(KEY))
>>> b
println(results.getAt("a"))
>>> null
println(results.get("a"))
>>> null
```

Is this "correct" behavior? Likely not--maybe a `Properties.getAt` would be in order.

Comment: Detailed explanation! Thanks.

Comment: @Bala No problem; it was interesting. I'd consider filing an enhancement request for this, actually; I think it violates the principle of least surprise. If you do, follow up here with a comment--if I don't see anything within a few days I might do it myself, but IMO you should get the credit for discovering it (if it hasn't been requested already, it seems like an obvious issue to me).

Comment: @D.Newton I am afraid, I might not have time to follow up with the Groovy developers after I file my request. So, if you are interested, please file an enhancement. Thanks!